# Proposed question - How quickly did Renaissance bakers work?

Tags: discussion

Proposed question:

> How much bread, (in loaves?) could a typical Renaissance baker's family pump out in 1 day?

Good question, or not?

Hmm... Research...

Well, this blogger has personal experience with Renaissance baking...

http://alicethecook.com/making-bread-the-renaissance-way/

The start of the actual baking can be extrapolated, if I knew how long it would take to warm up the oven enough for baking... Assuming that they start work at 6AM, add the oven warming time to that, and then assume they work until sunset?

Also, assuming that Renaissance bakers made bread for the whole city... Figuring out the percentage of a city's population that are bakers, and how much of the population actually got bread, and assuming that each baker's business provides the same amount of bread, then an amount of bread in Renaissance-bread's-plural-counting-noun per day can be guessed/calculated...

Well, according to [Wikipedia: Rome: Demographics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rome#Demographics):

After the fall of the Western Roman Empire, the city's population declined to less than 50,000 people. It continued to stagnate or shrink until the Renaissance. When the Kingdom of Italy annexed Rome in 1870, the city had a population of about 200,000. This increased to 600,000 by the eve of World War I.

So... assume 100,000 people in Rome... And, [since the middle classes and lower ate more bread than the upper classes](http://www.engr.psu.edu/MTAH/articles/flower_of_wheat.htm), assume everyone had 2 loaves of bread, daily.

Well, [[In] the United States... [1910's] per capita consumption of bread products was roughly 210 pounds.](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/bread.aspx)

So, what is the population of bakers... I could just guess by taking baker population in a current city and multiplying it by... 50?

When's the earliest census with job listings?

Comment: The question is good, but you will surely get down-votes, because you have not shown a minimal research. The research could be even showing why it is the problem *to perform* the research (eg. lack of sources, many sources and each saying something different etc.)

Comment: TBH minimal research is more like googling *"medieval bakery production level' and the first page of results are so and so*. In this case finding an answer is non-trivial and I doubt many users would begrudge you over the  lack of research if you say you found nothing.

Comment: @Semaphore - Well, I'm gonna go to sleep now, so if any of you feel like moving it or whatever, go ahead...

Comment: @Malandy You would have to post it as a question on the main site.

Comment: You can't move from meta. to main.? Didn't know that... Well, gonna try some more research...